# Magento Custom customer attribute not visible on Frontened

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.8

I created a module to add a custom attribute for customer registration and other forms.It is visible on backend but not visible on frontend.I want to show it on all forms on frontend.

I used it from this link:
http://www.silksoftware.com/magento-module-creator/

Comment: Where do you want to show that customer attribute and what is your attribute_code ?

Comment: Want to show on customer registration form and attribute code is weedpreference

Comment: Do you see the attribute id of attribute_code `weedpreference`  for the field **form_code** `customer_account_create` in your `customer_form_attribute` table ?

Comment: yes it is present there

Comment: Check the `is_visible` field value for your attribute in `customer_eav_attribute` table

Comment: Do you have any other idea?

Comment: still finding the exact reason

Comment: Could you access your customer attribute value on frontend something like this `<?php echo $this->getYourAttributeValue(); ?>` ??

Comment: found same thread here too [link](http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/10545/how-to-display-customer-attribute-on-frontend-in-magento)

Comment: 1) Check the visibility of your customer attribute
2) Update the registration template via xml and then add your field into the new template.
3) Try to access it in your customer form

Comment: it works when i add fields in customer/form/register.phtml.
I want to add fields from my custom template,don't want to edit directly phtml file.Say i created a file name newfields.phtml and how can I able to add this to register.phtml

Comment: thank you Slimshaaayyy for all help

Comment: post your code as answer to this question.

Answer (score 1):

Just added the fields into register.phtml template like:

> ```
> <div class="input-box">
>        <input type="text" name="driver_license_number" id="driver_license_number" value="" title="<?php echo $this->__('Driver License Number') ?>" class="input-text"/>
>   </div>
> ```

Just take care about name,name must be same as your attribute code.

Comment: How do I do this by not editing the base template. From my module itself.